# Google Play In-app Billing: Setting status of product to inactive and still check if it was bought?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

In my Android app I do have a in-app product which I don't want to sell anymore. But I still want to check if the user has already purchased it via `inventory.hasPurchase(REMOVE_ADS);` within `onQueryInventoryFinished` after I executed `queryInventoryAsync` on the `IabHelper`.

My app is already released and purchases of that product have been made, so I can't just test it by myself.

Now I wonder if I can set the status of that product to **inactive** or do I need to keep it **active**?

Comment: Hello Steffen, I am very interested about that too! Did you find the answer?

Comment: I guess we'll never know...

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find an answer. I just kept the product active and changed it's price.